# Rstudio shiny not finding image in www folder

Tags: r, shiny

I've got this code from a previous working example:

```
page_name="logo"
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel('Sortable list'),
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$script(src = "js/jquery-ui.min.js")),
      wellPanel(
        uiOutput('sortable_rui')
      ),
      wellPanel(
        uiOutput('sortable2_rui')
                ),
      wellPanel(
                h5(page_name),
                img(src=paste0(page_name,".png")),
                img(src=paste0("www/",page_name,".png"))
                )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('showData'),
      verbatimTextOutput('showorder'),
      tableOutput('showData2'),
      verbatimTextOutput('showorder2')
    )
  )
)
```

And here is what I've got inside the `www/` folder:

```
avilella@ubuntu64:/var/shiny-server/www/sortable/www$ ls -l
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 2 avilella avilella  4096 Jan 30 09:26 js
-rwxrwx--- 1 avilella avilella 67022 Feb 10 14:47 logo.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 avilella avilella   299 Jan 30 09:26 sort.css
```

Yet it's not finding the logo inside `www/`:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine it is just that the permission on the logo.png file does not allow regular user to see it. Try chmod 664 /var/shiny-server/www/sortable/www/logo.png from the command line

You don't need to specify www/ here so the following works:

```
img(src=paste0(page_name,".png")),
```

Comment: shouldn't that be ".png"?