# Getting local files to show in a shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the following code to try to show images in a datatable. I am unable to see local images mainly because I clearly dont understand paths with shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(here)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(DT::dataTableOutput("test")),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- data.frame(
    country = c('China', 'Belgium'),
    flag = c('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="/www/EndoMinerLogo.png" height="52"></img>'
    )
  )
  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({ DT::datatable(dat, escape = F) })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

My shiny app file is in the same folder as the folder www. (and I've tried both /www and without the "/"

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: try running the app with `runApp(PATH)` and `img src="EndoMinerLogo.png"`,...

Comment: OK great @BigDataScientist yes that did it. Do the files always have to be in a www folder?

Comment: @SebastianZeki The `www` folder will always work. You can set another folder with the function `addResourcePath`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very close to [Rstudio shiny not finding image in www folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680342/rstudio-shiny-not-finding-image-in-www-folder).

However, there is one trap i also encountered quite often. **Additionaly ensure a matching working directory.**
If you run the app per console and not via `runApp()` the working directory might be different to the folder including the shiny app (and the www folder).

So you might want to start the app via `runApp()`, because then the working directory is automatically set (or you set the working directory manually).

Given the correct working directory ensure you correctly reference the files in the www folder. As written in the linked Q/A remove the "www" in the path or use `addResourcePath()` as @StéphaneLaurent mentioned already in the comment, to place the files outside the www folder..